# What is the difference between “submit” and “deposit”?

Tags: meaning-in-context, vocabulary

I am trying to find out the difference between "submit" and "deposit" these words are very confusing when you visit to a bank and somebody ask you "what is the purpose of you to come here and you replied that "I came here to submit a payment" or "I came here to deposit a payment" out of these two sentences which is correct and why?

Comment: You may find  [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com) useful.

Comment: This almost sounds like a translation error. While one might *submit a **payment,*** that's normally in [ODO sense 2](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/submit) or sense 3. What did your own dictionary searches reveal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have never encountered the word *submit* used with "money"; it is sometimes used with "payment" - but that would mean paying for something, which is different from what you usually do in a bank.

COCA (the corpus of Contemporary American English) does not have a single instance of "submit money" (or of "submit the money" or "submit some money").

Comment: You deposit money at a bank; you submit a payment by sending it. So if you are standing there at the bank, "submit" sounds odd. You could submit funds by mail for deposit; but if you sent them, you might as well say that you sent them for deposit.